# This 'if' evaluation in Java with three simultaneous expressions

Tags: java

I had this question in my Java test where I had to assign values to `a` and `b` so this expression evaluates to true:

```
(a<=b && b<=a && a!=b)
```

Sadly, I had no idea what the answer was.

Comment: What are the types of `a` and `b`?

Comment: `a` and 'b' can be any number wrapper as long as they are the same. `Byte`, `Character` `Integer`, `Long`, `Float`, `Double` as `!=` compares references but `<=` compares the unboxed values.

Comment: If you like this puzzle, try `x != x + 0` has three possible types, and `x == -x` has 22 possible values/types.

Comment: Only three for the last one?  You're probably thinking that a `float` or `double` equal to NaN will use broken IEEE-754 equality, and a string will do a reference comparison between itself and a new string which has a '0' at the end.  Wouldn't any non-null value of any of the wrapper types work, though?

Comment: What a horrible test question.  Hope it was an advanced subject.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

There's a simple trick here.

You cannot think this through with boolean logic only. Using that, this combination...

- `a` is less than or equal to `b`, and
- `b` is less than or equal to `a`, and
- `a` is not equal to `b`

...would never return `true`.

However, the `!=` operator compares references if its operands are objects.

So, the following will return `true`:

```
Integer a = 1;
Integer b = new Integer(1);
System.out.println(a<=b && b<=a && a!=b);
```

What happens here is: `a` as an object reference is not equal to `b` as an object reference, although of course they hold equal integer values.

Comment: This assumes that `Integer` is never `intern`ed - which is a fair assumption for the higher values but some JVMs cache `-127 - 128`. You may be better to use `10000` or something.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon - He is using `new Integer(1);` which doesn't return values from local cache (unlike `Integer.valueOf()` ) . So it is fine i guess :)

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon was about to answer but ThwLostMind beat me to it. Explicitly initializing a `new Integer(int value)` defiles interning.

Comment: You absolutely can think this through Boolean logic (only not solely using it). Equality/inequality operators have nothing to do with the conjugations part.

Comment: I tried to find a passage in the JLS which guarantees that this works, but I haven't had any luck … nor have I been able to determine that it *doesn't*. Anybody have a quote?

Comment: @JörgWMittag See [15.20.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1): *"...operands ...must be...convertible to a primitive numeric type"* for `<=` and `>=`, and [15.21.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3), *"... result of == is true if ... both refer to the same object"* for `==`

Comment: I feel dirty upvoting this answer, because the question (not the OP's, but the question on the test) is so... icky. It's a brainteaser that's a fun gotcha, and possibly a neat way to see if someone can "think outside the box," but probably a pretty poor test of someone's Java knowledge.

Comment: @yshavit I have to disagree with you here. This *looks* like a fun trick, but it also implies being aware of some fundamentals of the Java language few people bother to investigate - here, `Number` wrapper classes, caching and object equality. I wouldn't be surprised to find questions like this in Oracle's 1Z0-804 exam for instance.

Comment: @Mena Knowledge of those things is necessary but not sufficient to answer this question, especially given that it depends on behavior that's generally frowned upon (comparing references using `!=`). If I showed somebody the answer and asked them to spot the bug, I would very much expect them to find it; but going the other way around, of presenting seemingly-buggy behavior and asking someone to create the bad code that triggers it... that seems less useful to me. YMMV, I guess. :)

Comment: This feels as evil as [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28818/21697)... *slow clap*

Comment: @h.j.k. nice one! Still laughing... pranks ahoy! :D